# Is the naturality condition a generalized commutativity law?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If objects and functors are equal ( $F=G$ and $a=b$) then $\alpha_a \circ Ff = Gf \circ \alpha_b$ translates to $\alpha_a \circ Ff = Ff \circ \alpha_a$.
If associativity is more basic than commutativity (even to the definition of category), is this the most basic or "deep" occurrence of a (the?) commutativity law?

Comment: Sure, why not? Doesn’t really seem like a question admitting an objective answer, but for instance the center of a monoid is indeed the set of elements constituting a natural endomorphism of the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unnatural+isomorphism):

"The term “natural” is used for traditional reasons, cf. EilenbergMac Lane45, and is an example of the common phenomenon that concepts branded natural, normal or regular tend to be rather non-generic or non-random. In fact, Eilenberg and MacLane comment (cf. p. 233, first paragraph in loc. cit) on the term, associating it with an intuition of simultaneity, rather than genericity. **This intuition is in tune with conceiving of naturality as generalized commutatitivity.**"